# Is this count as Inputting actual data in to forecasting? Then how would I use it in the real world?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

I'm working on a time series models which forecasting a salesQty, I'm using a GRU as a model and have a question Here's a code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GRU, Dense

# Extract the sales quantity values
for i, sales_data in enumerate(df_array[:5]):
    best_lag = int(lags_dict[f'dataset_{i+1}'])
    data = sales_data['SalesQty'].values.reshape(-1, 1)  # Convert to 2D array
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data)

    # Split the data into training and test sets
    train_size = int(len(data_scaled) * 0.7)  # 80% for training
    train_data = data_scaled[:train_size]
    test_data = data_scaled[train_size:]

    window_size = best_lag

    X_train, y_train = [], []
    for i in range(len(train_data) - window_size):
        X_train.append(train_data[i:i+window_size])
        y_train.append(train_data[i+window_size])
    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

    # Create and compile the LSTM model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(GRU(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(window_size, 1)))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=16)

    # Perform forecasting on the test set
    X_test, y_test = [], []
    for i in range(len(test_data) - window_size):
        X_test.append(test_data[i:i+window_size])
        y_test.append(test_data[i+window_size])
    X_test, y_test = np.array(X_test), np.array(y_test)

    # Make predictions
    predictions = model.predict(X_test)

    # Scale the predictions back to the original range
    predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)

    # Ensure predicted values are not less than 0
    predictions = np.where(predictions < 0, 0, predictions)
```

What I'm seeing is that the code is Getting a value from SalesQty then split in to train and test set. But isn't that making a testing set have actual value when inputting it in to
`# Make predictions predictions = model.predict(X_test)`
What if it's an real world problem where I would need to forecast a data which doesn't even happen yet therefore no SalesQty to input? How do I make a forecast from that?